# Show/Hide multiple Divs with changing classes for trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

I don´t work much with javascript and I googled a lot the last few hours to figure out my problem. I guess I just don´t know the right words to search for.

This is what I want to achieve. A list of Links with a small arrow next to it. When you click on a link, a hidden div is shown and the arrow should move down to show that the text is "open". When I click on another text, the arrow should move up again and the div should be hidden. The other div would open accordingly. But the code is still a bit buggy. When I click on a link it gets the class "expanded" - but this class is not being automatically removed when I click on another item.

Here is my code so far... It doesnt work at all on jsfiddle, don´t know why http://jsfiddle.net/DvH75/

```
var _hidediv = null
   function showdiv(id) {
   if(_hidediv)
      _hidediv();
   var div = document.getElementById(id);
   div.style.display = 'block';
    $(".toggle").on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
      });
   _hidediv = function () { div.style.display = 'none'; };
   }
```

And this is an example of what I want to archieve. The only difference is that I want an open item to close once another is opened:
https://www.facebook.com/help/473865172623776/

I hope you understand my question and can help me
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toggleClass() call is adding the class to the one clicked, but I don't see you removing the class of the previous clicked.  What I would do is something like:

```
$('.expanded').each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
});
```

**EDIT: Working Example**

I spent some time in jsFiddle and got [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7pXpK/) (warning, jsFiddler doesn't seem to work in IE8, so use FireFox or Chrome to view the example).

First, I dropped the *'display: none;*' from the **UL.fade_text li div** style in main.css as it's not needed any longer.

Next, I added class markers for all the *div*s.  I could have probably done something else, but this was a quick-n-dirty example.

Last, I re-wrote the JS to be more jQuery-ish.  I made a function that will show or hide the divs based on if it finds an anchor tag with the class toggle that also has the class expanded.  Then, I added a click event handler to all the anchor tags, again using jQuery, that calls the showHideDivs() function.  I also added a call to showHideDivs() in the $(document).ready() so that the initial state is set properly.

Here is the new JS code.  It could probably be tweeked to optimize things a bit, but it works like I would expect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function showHideDivs() {
        $('.showHideDiv').each(function () {
            if ($(this).prevAll('a.toggle:first').hasClass('expanded')) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    }

    $('a.toggle').click(function () {
        var addExpanded = !$(this).hasClass('expanded');
        $('a.toggle').removeClass('expanded');
        if(addExpanded) {
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        }
        showHideDivs();
    });

    showHideDivs();
});
```

I think the benefits of this approach is that it will gracefully degrade for browsers that have issues with the JS or just have JS turned off.  The end result is that those people would see all the div tags expanded.

Comment: yes, also using selectors on class like change all .open to .close after you do a .close to .open would be more appropriate for ur case.

Comment: Or use `$('.expanded').removeClass('expanded');`

Comment: I tried this code and also the shorter one in the answer from digitalfresh. Its still not working properly. Sometimes the class expanded is added only after a second click on the link. Especially on the first item on the list its pretty buggy.
Have a look at my site here (sorry, its german... but you will get the idea hopefully):
http://web3.server.e-astro.de/know-how/astronomie/

Comment: I just took a look at your site, and it looks to me like the "toggle" stuff is working perfectly, its the showing/hiding of the div tag that's not working.  I am not quite sure I understand how the _hidediv is even working.  I also don't understand why you are using jQuery from some of the stuff, but non-jQuery for grabbing the div tag and setting the style.

Comment: Because I don´t know much about jQuery. I combined to codes that I found in different places and they kinda work - though I don´t really understand them :/  
Right know the divs are opening fine, but the class "expanded" is sometimes not added after the first click. I have to click on the link again and then the class is added. Also I´m looking for a functionality to close the open div. Right know if I click on a different link the previous div "closes". But I can´t close the active div. So once I "opened" any link, I can´t close all of them again...

Comment: I took your site code for the UL list and played with it a bit in jsFiddler.  Results are in the edit I made to the original post.

Comment: Thank you very much!! That´s it. Its working exactly like I wanted... Just one more minor thing. What would I have to do to make it look a bit smoother? So that it doesnt open instantly but slides in or something? I´ve this is too much effort, then forget about it. Would be nice though :) 
Thanks again allready!!

Comment: Oh and one more thing I just realised. When I click on any item, everytime the window scrolls to the top of the page because of the # sign. Can this be disabled for this list? Because its not very nice if you have to scroll down first after you opened an item.

Comment: jQuery has a bunch of "effects".  For instance, change the "show()" and "hide()" to "slideDown()" and "slideUp()" and you will get a nice sliding effect.  The API guide is a good place to start looking for effects:  http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/.  As for the anchor tags, you don't need to use them at all.  You can attach an event handler, like click, to any page element.  I forked the fiddler with an example that removes the anchor tags and uses just the h4's instead:  http://jsfiddle.net/pxtyw/

Comment: PERFECT... All thumbs up for your answer. Thank you very much for your help. This is the first time I´m using this "forum" and I must say, I´m impressed about the help I´m getting here. Very awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTML from your jsFiddle, the jQuery below should work as expected:

```
$('a.toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded').next('div').toggleClass('open');
});
```

As long as you declare the `.open` class in your CSS:

```
ul.fade_text li div.open { display: block; }
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DvH75/3/

Also, you don't need the `onclick="showdiv('astro-1'); return false;"` on your `<a>` tags with the unobtrusive script.

Comment: Tried this code and like the previous answer, nothing happens at all anymore unfortunately... See here:
http://web3.server.e-astro.de/know-how/astronomie/test2.php

Comment: You're including the jQuery code before the DOM is loaded so nothing is happening. You'll need to wrap that code in `$(function(){ do stuff... });` or in the `$(document).ready()` so it fires after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: Thank you for your trouble. But with the code from codechimp everything works fine and as i wanted it to be. So this topic can be closed. Thans anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. Just hide all the contained divs and show the current one. You don't need to keep track of the last one.

```
$(function() {
$(".fade_text .toggle").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".fade_text div").hide();
    $(".fade_text .toggle").removeClass("expanded");
    $(this).addClass("expanded").next("div").show();
});
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4JFcK/4/

Edit: Also remove all expanded anchors on click

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately now the divs don´t open at all anymore and pretty much nothing happens... See here:
http://web3.server.e-astro.de/know-how/astronomie/test1.php

Comment: That is because the code is executed before the page loads. I updated the answer of how you would do it with $(document).ready().

Comment: Thank you for your trouble. But with the code from codechimp everything works fine and as i wanted it to be. So this topic can be closed. Thans anyway